# Emacs/Tramp fails to connect with ssh key equiped with a passphrase

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp, ssh

I have problem connecting via ssh using Tramp in Emacs on MS-Windows whenever the private ssh key I use is configured with a passphrase.

Here's the problem :

**I. What works :**

1. On the command line `ssh -i path/to/shh_key_WITH_NO_passphrase login@hostname`, works just fine and I'm connected to remote server.
2. On the command line `ssh -i path/to/shh_key_WITH_passphrase login@hostname`, I've got a prompt asking for my passphrase for this key :

[image]

And then I'm connected to the remote server.

3. In Emacs : `C-x C-f RET /sshx: RET ssh_key_WITH_NO_passphrase`, the connection succeed and I'm able to go through files and open them :

[image]

**II. What don't works :**

1. In Emacs : `C-x C-f RET /sshx: RET ssh_key_WITH_passphrase`

What happens with previous point 1. :

I get a `Opening connection nil for ssh_key_WITH_passphrase using ssh...` and it just hang there and I have to hit `C-g` like continously to get it out of there :

[image]

**III. How to reproduce the bug :**

1. Get GNU Emacs 28.2 running on MS-Windows 10
2. Create two ssh key to connect to a remote server, one with a passphrase and one without, see [gitlab's help page for that](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).
3. Set `tramp-default-method` to "ssh" or "sshx" (either don't work on my side) with for example `M-: RET (setq tramp-default-method "sshx")`
4. Try to connect with one of the 2 keys, the one with a passphrase should not work, for that I've configure a `config` file in the `.ssh/` in which I describe how OpenSSH should connect with remote server :

```
Host Co_No_Phrase
     HostName hostname
     Port 22
     User login
          IdentityFile HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
          IdentitiesOnly yes

Host Co_Phrase
     HostName hostname
     Port 22
     User login
          IdentityFile HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_phrase
          IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then :

_ `C-x C-f RET /sshx: RET Co_No_Phrase` should tell Emacs to use Tramp to connect to hostname with the key that has no passphrase.

_ `C-x C-f RET /sshx: RET Co_Phrase` should tell Emacs to use Tramp to connect to hostname with the key that has a passphrase.

I love using Emacs for coding remotly on clusters, and never had any problem when I was on Linux, but for professionnal reasons I have to be on Windows now, poor me... It's awful, pls help me ?

Thanks a lot to the community

Comment: I doubt that your example works. At least a colon is missing, and you should do `C-x C- RET /sshx::` . Furthermore, it is hard to debug with this informatiion. I don't understand what you mean with `ssh_key_WITH_NO_passphrase` - I'm not aware of Emacs/Tramp asking for an ssh key.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus I've edit things for more clarity, sorry always difficult to be clear spot on publication. I've added a "Reproduce the bug" section if it can help debugging

Comment: Can't do better than that in terms of writing a post for me..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the precise recipe. I could reproduce it on my Windows 10 VM, running Emacs 30.0.50 and OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1. After instrumenting the `ssh` call in Tramp with `-v`, there is

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\albinus/tmp/key_with_passphrase RSA SHA256:hqITNMbzDAJmafsNVNJLBffCiqGJ0Eoux3y+H8TfZZw explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\albinus/tmp/key_with_passphrase RSA SHA256:hqITNMbzDAJmafsNVNJLBffCiqGJ0Eoux3y+H8TfZZw explicit
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
```

So Tramp (Emacs) cannot read the passphrase. As solution, I've started `ssh-agent` as described in [Key-based authentication in OpenSSH for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement?source=recommendations). Note, that you must run `powershell` as administrator. And then, apply

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
PS C:\Windows\system32> Start-Service ssh-agent
PS C:\Windows\system32> ssh-add C:\Users\albinus\tmp\key_with_passphrase
Enter passphrase for C:\Users\albinus\tmp\key_with_passphrase:
Identity added: C:\Users\albinus\tmp\key_with_passphrase (albinus@win10)
```

And indeed, the remote connection `/sshx:co_phrase:` opens then as expected.

Comment: Thks for the answer, looks like it's the right direction. But I've still got a problem : `ssh-add /path/to/key_with_passphrase` returns `Permissions for '~\\.ssh\\id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.`
So I've tried to change users permissions to different  ones but no success : `PS > icacls.exe .\id_rsa
.\id_rsa AUTORITE NT\Système:(N)
         INTRA\TC273997:(N)
         IS243769\adminus:(F)
         BUILTIN\Administrateurs:(F)`

Comment: During my tests, I've got the same problem. https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open has helped me.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thks a lot